# Office365 REST API returns Unauthorized with C# ADAL

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, adal, office365api

I'm building a WPF-App. First get Events and later on create Events via O365 RestAPI.

I'm able to get events with:

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                    string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    string graphRequest = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=" + today + "T00:00:00&endDateTime=" + today + "T23:59:00&$select=Subject,organizer,start,end,attendees&$orderby=start/datetime%20asc");
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, graphRequest);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = HttpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        throw new WebException(response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
```

But when I try to create Events, I will receive a "Unauthorized" using the same Token. My App have permissions to read and write calenders.

This is my code:

```
string postBody = "{'Subject':" + "'Discuss the Calendar REST API'," +
                            "'Body':{ " +
                                          "'ContentType':'HTML'," +
                              "'Content': 'I think it will meet our requirements!'},"
                           + "'Start': { DateTime: '" + 
                              start + "',"
                                    + " 'TimeZone': 'W. Europe Standard Time'}," +
                               "'End':{'DateTime': '" + end + "'," +
                                    "'TimeZone': 'W. Europe Standard Time'},"
                                + "'Attendees':[{" +
                                "'EmailAddress':{"
                                 + "'Address': '" + MailTB.Text + "'"
                                + 
                                " },"
                                + "'Type': 'Required'}]}";


    var emailBody = new StringContent(postBody, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    string graphRequest = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/events");
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, graphRequest);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"");
        HttpResponseMessage response = MainWindow.HttpClient.PostAsync(graphRequest, emailBody).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new WebException(response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
```

Comment: What's the detail error message? Is it helpful to renew a token for this issue?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT
This is what I get:
    Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Mon, 15 May 2017 14:02:51 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""
    X-FEServer: HE1PR0902CA0019
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    request-id: a95cc2b6-7e90-4fe7-8f26-24c13f570f29

I refreshed the token, everythigns still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, graphRequest);
>       request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
>       request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"");
>           HttpResponseMessage response = MainWindow.HttpClient.PostAsync(graphRequest, emailBody).Result;

The code you you send the post request will not send the headers you set since all the headers are set for the `request` parameter but you were not using it in the post.

To send the post with access_token, you can refer code below:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"");
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(graphRequest, emailBody).Result;
```

Comment: Thank you! There was a mistake in the emailBody aswell, but now it's running!